# Radio button fires ajax once, but then doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, radio-button

I have the following form with a radio button that repeats for each record. If the value of $item['active'] for a given record is 0, and I click the radio button to make it 1, the ajax fires and everything works as desired. The new value is 1; however, if I then click the other button to return the variable's value to 0, nothing happens. It is as if the ajax fires once and then is no longer available.

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->form_action; ?>" method="post">
    <p class="hide"><input name="status" type="text" value="" /></p>
    <table id="manageItAll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">

        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->translate('Title');?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->translate('Status');?></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <?php $ind = 0; ?>
        <?php foreach ($this->items as $item) {;?>
            <tr id="<?php echo $item['id']; ?>">
                <td data-label="Title"><span class="orangelink"><?php echo $item->title; ?></span></td>

                <td align="left" style="padding-left:22px"
                    class="color-status-<?php echo $item['active']; ?>">
                    <?php if (in_array($item['active'], array(0, 1))) { ?>
                        <input type="radio" name="item[<?php echo $ind; ?>][status]"
                               value="1" <?php if ($item['active'] == 1) echo 'checked'; ?>>Active
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="item[<?php echo $ind; ?>][status]"
                               value="0" <?php if ($item['active'] == 0) echo 'checked'; ?>>Inactive
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <?php echo $item['active']; ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php $ind++; ?>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if (typeof ind == "undefined") {
        ind = 0;
    }
    $('input[type="radio"]').live('change', function () {
        var status = this.value;
        var id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "?module=items&controller=listing&action=changeStatus",
            data: 'id=' + id + '&status=' + status,
            beforeSend: function () {

                if (status == '0') {
                    $('#' + id).animate({
                        'backgroundColor': '#FFBFBF'
                    }, 400);
                } else {
                    $('#' + id).animate({
                        'backgroundColor': '#A3D1A3'
                    }, 400);
                }
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result == 'ok') {
                    $.get(window.location.href, function (data) {
                        $('#' + id).html($(data).find('#' + id).html());
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $("#" + id + "").animate({'backgroundColor': 'transparent'}, 400);
                            deletePage();
                        }, 500);
                    });
                } else {
                    alert(result);
                    $("#" + id + "").animate({'backgroundColor': 'transparent'}, 400);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: http://www.screencast.com/t/SvDkzCt7ftlY

Comment: Tx @WEBjuju, I actually can get the two different radio buttons to click, but after the first click triggers the ajax, subsequent clicks on the same item's radio button does not. Any ideas?

Comment: i had no problem with subsequent clicks either.  have you checked your javascript console for errors?

Comment: @WEBjuju, the console says: Uncaught ReferenceError: deletePage is not defined(…).   When I remove deletePage, the same thing happens.

Comment: @WEBjuju, I wanted to let you know the solution for this one:
I swapped $('input[type="radio"]').live('change', function () { -- for --  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {. 
Then I swapped  $(document).ready(function() -- for --  head.ready('jquery', function () {.
Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hi @WEBjuju, I have another question on the above, if you have a second. I want to define the title variable in the same javascript function, but I can't figure that out. Any ideas?  var title = ????

Answer (score 0):

Try change the

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
```

to

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change',function () {
```

Comment: Sorry @synz, no luck with this.

Comment: Emm. Do you really need to use headJS?

Comment: If you can. 
Try load jquery and change the 

    head.ready('jquery', function () { 

to

    $(document).ready(function(){

Comment: No luck, @synz.

Comment: Hi @synz, I wanted to let you know the solution for this one:
I swapped $('input[type="radio"]').live('change', function () { -- for --  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {. 
Then I swapped  $(document).ready(function() -- for --  head.ready('jquery', function () {.
Thanks again for your help.

Comment: No problem.. I'm glad to hear you can solve that.

No wonder on() method not working. 
You're using the old version of Jquery.
The live() method was deprecated in jQuery start with ver1.7+ if I'm not wrong and was removed in latest version.

Maybe you should consider to update your jQuery ver.

Comment: Hi @synz, I have another question on the above, if you have a second. I want to define the title variable in the same javascript function, but I can't figure that out. Any ideas?  var title = ???

Comment: What do you mean? title variable for? each radio?

Comment: I mean in the code, foreach ($this->items as $item), I have two variables, Status and Title. Title is define here:  <td data-label="Title"><span class="orangelink"><?php echo $item->title; ?></span></td> I want to use the value of title in the function: $('input[type="radio"]').live('change', function () {. I have defined the value of Status (var status = this.value;), but I don't know how to define the value of Title (var title = ????)

Comment: Perfect, @synz. Thanks very much!